# Keep or remove insignificant covariance values when modifying CFA model?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, covariance, goodness-of-fit, confirmatory-factor

I am working to improve goodness of fit in a CFA model and am wondering about if I should retain added covariance values that are insignificant. I am adding covariances that are indicated by modification indices one at a time.

1. If I add covariance to the model and it is insignificant but doesn't harm (or even improves) model fit, should I remove it from the model and try the next highest suggested modification instead, or should I keep it in?
2. If I add a covariance in and it is significant, but after I add additional stuff from later modifications and the previous covariance is not significant anymore, should I then remove that covariance?

Bonus question: If RMSEA, SRMR, and CFI are looking great, at what point can I be happy with the chi 2 p value? .05? .10?

Comment: Re: bonus question: if your sample size is large, the ratio of sample size / nr of estimated parameters is adequate, and other fit indices are good, you don't have to care about the chi-square p-value much, it is often trivially significant with large sample sizes.

Comment: Its a pretty small sample size. N = 155 and df = 79

Comment: And how many observed variables? But yeah that's not very large sample so you shouldn't ignore the chi-square result.